KDE neon, touchpad, few settings available. How to access more settings. I remember that installing a package allows access to more settings
I'm using KDE neon, and I've got a question about the touchpad settings.
I remember that when installing some software package, I was able to access more of the touchpad's settings.
Current available settings (few touchpad settings):

Image from my older laptop showing more available settings:

Does anyone know which package I should install to get the additional available settings?
I want to activate "middle mouse click" by pressing the top right corner on the touchpad.

Actually, it might have been additional touchpad drivers that I want to install.

Connected: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185327/how-to-have-touchpad-settings-in-kubuntu-as-advanced-as-in-opensuse

If you have a Synaptics TouchPad, perhaps information from How can I enable/disable the synaptics touchpad in Debian 9 with libinput? will help. It has the package name as xserver-xorg-input-synaptics.

xserver-xorg-input-synaptics already installed.

@842Mono how about xserver-xorg-input-multitouch?

it's not installed. Not sure I want to edit my system much. Have you tried it? There's this comment on bugs.kde.org https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=489202 Nate says that what we're mentioning isn't supported in Plasma 6.

@842Mono yes, i have it installed, but i'm on plasma 5.27.11; i see all the options your old laptop screenshot shows

I'm using plasma version 6.0.4.
